# Android Emulator claims “WHPX is not configured”, crashes

Tags: android-emulator

The Android Emulator launched from Visual Studio 2019 for Xamarin development throws this message before launching:

> WHPX is not configured
>
> Turn on "Windows Hypervisor Platform" feature to switch to the Native Hypervisor and accelerate your emulator.

This is despite that Hyper-V is installed, according to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration).

[image: Hyper-V enabled in Windows Features]

This is possibly related to the Emulator crashing after some time with no error message, or displaying this when launched from the Android Device Manager:

> Please check if you can update your video driver.
>   If it doesn't help, try to Edit the AVD and set "hw.gpu.mode=off".

This is on a machine that used to run the emulator previously, just a fresh installation of Windows.

Comment: I've decided to post this as a question despite already having solved this, because there are few hits on Google for these error messages and I have spent far too much time on this before finding out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is actually correct. On newer versions of Windows, “Windows Hypervisor Platform” (WHPX) is a separate feature on the Windows Features list.

[image]

Even the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration) have been updated to mention this. (Though it wasn't there when I was dealing with this problem and spent way too much time on it, sigh.)